# how to associate azure dns with a running linux VM

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

So I purchased a domain via azure DNS. Lets say `foo.com`. Prior to this I have created and bought up my linux VM. Its ubuntu 17.04 server. I can see a provision to configure DNS for the VM. However, instead of `foo.com`, which is what I want, I get `foo.<region>.cloudapp.azure.com`.

I don't see a way to associate my dns name to the running vm instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, Azure is **not** a domain registrar, we can't buy domain name from it.

If you want to create a **FQDN** for this Linux VM, we can create DNS name in Public IP address configuration:

[image]

If you buy a domain name from other domain registrar, we should add **A record** to Azure VM's public IP address, for example, buy a domain name from `register.com`, we should add A record like this:

[image]

Here a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580711/how-to-assign-a-domain-to-my-website-hosted-in-azure-linux-vm/43580857#43580857), please refer to it.

Comment: So the domain must have a single A record? Not multiple?

Comment: @deostroll we can use A record or CNAME, we need to map your domain name to your VM.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create an A record that points to the public IP address of the VM. Let's say you'd want to host a website, you could create an A record pointing www.foo.com to the public IP address of the VM. This would require a static public IP address though. 
You mentioned you are using Azure DNS - you may want to check here (if you haven't already): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-getstarted-portal

Alternatively, you could also use a CNAME record to point foo.com or any other URL to your VM. The advantage would be that you would not need a static IP but could point your CNAME entry to the FQDN you can define in the portal.
This article is for classic Service Manager deployments in Azure but the idea is the same: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just learned that azure is not a domain registrar. :-( So I am not clear how exactly azure DNS helps... is this product an intra azure DNS sort of package?